# How to set the accuracy of the sikuli?

Tags: sikuli

i have a problem,
 i need press on a elementin to the table,but select the elements that are similar

example : element is prueba111111

but in table contains 
-prueba111111
-prueba111112
-prueba111113

looks so similar that it looks for matches and selects what it looks like

click(findText('example'))

Comment: This may be useful for you: http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html#Settings.MinSimilarity

Comment: Mind giving a little more information? I see you're finding text in an example but what exactly are you trying to do with the similar things?

Comment: are you using Python or Java?

Answer (score 0):

Using the findText function there is no way to increase the accuracy. It finds the first match when searching from the top left to the bottom right (doc link [here](https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/news.html)).

Your best approach may be to limit the region in which you're looking for the text. If you have a general idea of where it will be in relation to a constant image, the [Region functions](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Region.html) left(), right(), above(), and below() may help in limiting where you look.

Alternatively, if the image will be the same every time, you can use an image of the text you're looking for to find it.